# How to prevent user input and create a read-only mode in tmux window?

Tags: tmux

I would like to create a read-only mode for a specific window within a `tmux` session. I want to prevent any user input or interactions in that window, effectively making it read-only. Changing the window option to enable/disable this feature would be perfect.

I have searched for options within `tmux`, but it seems there is no built-in feature specifically for a read-only mode. Ideally, I am looking for a solution that allows me to make a window read-only in `tmux` while still displaying the contents and allowing other users to observe the session.

An example would be that users can comfortably monitor the log changes using the `watch` command without any risk of unintentional interference. Any suggestions or guidance on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve a read-only mode for a `tmux` window (pane<sup>[3](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Getting-Started#sessions-windows-and-panes)</sup>) by disabling input for panes. Run the following `tmux` command<sup>[1](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/tmux/tmux.1.en.html#select-pane) [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/tmux/comments/ytplkt/lock_and_unlock_the_current_window_pane_with_only/)</sup> to disable input for current pane

```
tmux select-pane -d
```

To enable input in pane, run (in `tmux` `:` prompt)

```
select-pane -e
```

---

<sup>1 https://manpages.debian.org/testing/tmux/tmux.1.en.html#select-pane

2 https://www.reddit.com/r/tmux/comments/ytplkt/lock_and_unlock_the_current_window_pane_with_only/

3 https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Getting-Started#sessions-windows-and-panes</sup>

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I was able to set my specific window with `tmux select-pane -t "$sn:$i" -d` where `sn` is the session name and `i` is the window index.